# Javascript Jigsaw with image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://codepen.io/TheEnd/pen/mEzVAE

The link above is a jigsaw game i found on codepen. I wish to make the image that is the jigsaw to be an image uploaded by the user. So the jigsaw is an image they choose. I want to do this with Javascript i understand PHP may be easier but i want a javascript/jquery application. The code below is what i believe can solve this issue but i dont know how to implement it as a img src and bring both codes together any help would appreciated.

```
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
<script>
   function previewFile(){
       var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
       var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
       var reader  = new FileReader();

       reader.onloadend = function () {
           preview.src = reader.result;
       }

       if (file) {
           reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
       } else {
           preview.src = "";
       }
  }

  previewFile();  //calls the function named previewFile()
  </script>
```

Comment: A user image might not fit the exact size, so scaling-cropping should be done. I cannot see that part in your code... or is that already handled by that plugin?

Comment: the scale cropping will become an issue but something i can resolve later, this stage however is just getting it to work as im slightly confused on successfully putting the 2 codes together which is what im confused with at the moment.